# Вызов метода для неизвестного элемента WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public void FunctionA(Object element)
{
 element.Items.Clear();
}
```

Пример использования:

```
FunctionA(checkedListBox1);
```

В функцию `FunctionA` будут поступать аргументы только `checkedListBox` и `comboBox`, у обоих элементов есть метод `.Items.Clear()`;

Как сделать чтобы это заработало ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void FunctionA(IList aList)
{
  aList.Clear();
}

FunctionA(checkedListBox1.Items);
FunctionA(comboBox1.Items);
```

*Update*

> Что делать если в случае добавления checkedListBox1, нужно по
>   умолчанию чекбокс в положении cheked.

Ну нет чудес.

```
if (aList is CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection)
{
  ((CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection)aList).Add(Text, true);
}
else
{
  aList.Add(Text);
}
```

Comment: Ошибка 3 Использование универсального тип "System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>" требует аргументы типа "1". Ругается на "IList aList"

Comment: @LorDo добавьте `using System.Collections;` в начало файла

Comment: есть ещё нюанс. Что делать если в случае добавления checkedListBox1, нужно по умолчанию чекбокс в положении cheked. (Если использовать ту же стему для кода aList.Add(Text);

Answer (score 0):

Ну как-то так:

```
if (element.GetType() == typeof(CheckedListBox)) ((CheckedListBox)element).Items.Clear();
else if (element.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox)) ((CheckedListBox)element).Items.Clear();
```